# Is it possible to validate a cell using data validation?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I know it's possible to set data validation on a cell. However is it possible to actually validate the cell? Or is this it?, only setting validation rules but never actually validating values?

Ive been roaming the source code for a "Validate" function/method, but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Setting Data Validation is setting the rules by which data entered in that cell will be validated when the generated file is opened in MS Excel... PHPExcel itself trusts the script developer to validate any values they store in that cell themselves.

Comment: Is there any where i can get documentation for the different validation functions to get me going on creating my own validator functionality?

Comment: Looking at the API docs and looking at the source code, which show you how the validator is structured in PHPExcel; reading the Excel format specifications, which have some description about how the validation about the different options